# How to Iterate Multiple Combinations in For Loop with DateTimeStamp

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with TimeStamp Values and Integer values say A,B,InTime and Standard .
I am looking for All the Combinations with A,B and Standard where Standard Time Does Not have Any Duplicates. If Any Duplicates are found they need to be Modified with 15 mins Range .

Input Image :

[image]

Input Sample :

```
    A   B   InTime               Standard
0   1   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
1   2   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
2   3   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
3   4   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
4   5   1   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
5   1   2   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
6   2   2   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
7   3   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
8   4   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
9   5   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
10  1   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00
11  2   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00
12  3   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00
13  4   3   2020-05-21 13:30:00 2020-05-21 14:30:00
14  5   3   2020-05-21 13:30:00 2020-05-21 14:30:00
```

Expected Output :
[image]

Code Tried :

```
for each in data.A.unique():
    for t in data.B.unique():
        if data.Standard[t] == data.Standard[t+1]:
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Hi , I had tried with Nested Loop with A and B and tried to check with  If Condition 
 for Standard  , I am getting the Value Error : The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() , When I Tried to apply any() and all() , I am getting all the values into If Condition

Comment: Please edit your question including the code that you tried (+ the error stack trace). Could you also copy paste a small part of your table (not as image) so that we can copy it and try to help you? Thanks

Comment: A B InTime Standard
0 1 1 2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
1 2 1 2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
2 3 1 2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
3 4 1 2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
4 5 1 2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
5 1 2 2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
6 2 2 2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
7 3 2 2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
8 4 2 2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
9 5 2 2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
10 1 3 2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00
11 2 3 2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00

Comment: I tried Something like this :
for each in data.A.unique():
    for t in data.B.unique():
        if data.Standard[t] == data.Standard[t+1]:

Comment: I still have a question for you sorry. I don't get this: row 4 of the input dataframe A==5 and B==1 with time 10.20. Then row 5 A==1 and B==2 and time 10.20. In this case, in the output table in row 5 the time is increased, but the combination of A and B is not a duplicated so it should not be increased by 15 minutes. Can you explain this please?

Comment: I am Sorry I had not Initiated correctly , It will not only check with A, B values but It will also check  with Standard that no two values are Same .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_standard = []
for i, item in data.groupby("Standard"):
    temp_list = [item.iloc[0,3]]
    for j in range(1,item.shape[0]):
        temp_list.append(temp_list[j-1]+pd.Timedelta("15 m"))
    new_standard.extend(temp_list)

data["Standard"] = new_standard
```

Output:

```
    A   B   InTime              Standard
0   1   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:15:00
1   2   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:30:00
2   3   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 09:45:00
3   4   1   2020-05-21 09:00:00 2020-05-21 10:00:00
4   5   1   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:20:00
5   1   2   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:35:00
6   2   2   2020-05-21 10:00:00 2020-05-21 10:50:00
7   3   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 11:50:00
8   4   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 12:05:00
9   5   2   2020-05-21 11:15:00 2020-05-21 12:20:00
10  1   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:15:00
11  2   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:30:00
12  3   3   2020-05-21 12:15:00 2020-05-21 13:45:00
13  4   3   2020-05-21 13:30:00 2020-05-21 14:30:00
14  5   3   2020-05-21 13:30:00 2020-05-21 14:45:00
```

Comment: Thanks @DavideBrex  It was very helpful .